# Put links with conditions in a row of kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add action into a grid based on the state of the record, In a web-grid it looks like this

```
grid.Column(format:
@<text>
    @if(item.State == State.Working)
    {
        @: | @Html.ActionLink("Pause", "Pause", new { id = item.Id })
    }else if(item.State == State.Pause)
    {
        @:| @Html.ActionLink("Continue", "Continue", new { id = item.Id })
    }
</text>               
)
```

How something as this can be done in the grid of kendo?

EDIT: I need this for the Ajax grid version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
 columns.Bound(x => x.State ).ClientTemplate( 
          "# if ( State == 'Working' ) { #" +
               Html.ActionLink("Pause", "Pause", new { id = item.Id })..ToHtmlString() +
          "# } else { #" +
               Html.ActionLink("Continue", "Continue", new { id = item.Id})..ToHtmlString() +
          "# } #"
                                           ).Title("State")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works as charm :)